# Android Доступ к файлам приложения

Tags: android

Записываю файл во внутреннюю память приложения следующим образом:

```
   String fileName = "someFile.data";
 try {
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
                        openFileOutput(fileName,MODE_APPEND)));
    bw.write(model);
    bw.close();
      } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
     }
```

Возможно ли его найти при помощи проводника в папках Android/data/app_name/...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нет, он записывается в `/data/data/package_name/files/...`.
Проводник (Андроид приложение) не имеет туда доступа без рута.
В студии `Device File Explorer` может показать файлы Ваших приложений.

Чтобы записать файл в `Android/data/app_name/...` (которую видно в проводнике) нужно использовать [`getExternalFilesDir`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getExternalFilesDir(java.lang.String)):

```
String fileName = "someFile.data";
File file = new File(getContext().getExternalFilesDir("files"), fileName);
BufferedWriter bw = null;
try {
    bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file, true));
    bw.write(model);
    bw.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    if (bw != null) {
        try { 
            bw.close();
        } cath (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```